# Does time move faster (less gravity) or slower (more velocity) in an airplane?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, time-dilation

From what I've gathered about special and general relativity, flying across the Atlantic should simultaneously speed up time for the person in the plane (because they experience less gravity at higher altitude) as well as slow down time (because they speed up relative to the person who doesn't travel).

Which of these 2 effects is stronger ? And how much stronger ?

I tried finding answers to this online but so far haven't found anything conclusive.

Comment: There's some relevant info (with graphs) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Combined_effect_of_velocity_and_gravitational_time_dilation

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/airtim.html#c3

Comment: The spectral shift due to the Doppler effect is 100,000 times greater than the gravitational effect or Einstein effect : https://luth.obspm.fr/~luthier/gourgoulhon/fr/master/relatM2.pdf ,page 70 (in French)

Comment: @TheTiler did I understand correctly that the Doppler effect is only relevant if two observers are moving relative to each other ? In my case I'm more interested in the case where the air plane comes back to its original position and then you compare the two clocks, the one that moved and the one that stayed on earth. Otherwise, could you please provide any references explaining in English how the Doppler effect causes time dilation ? The links I found only talked about kinetic or gravitational time dilation.

Comment: For the transverse Doppler effect T'=γ T, for a single wave, for n waves (event: switching on and off of a laser for example) it is nT'=Δt'= γ nT = γ Δt.

Comment: @OP if you want to do estimates of this yourself, the time dilation due to velocity (special relativity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the excellent comments below my question, I found this very helpful Wikipedia article which included the expected and observed effects of both phenomena.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment#Results

In summary:

[image]

If you're interested not in planes but in orbiting satellites, this link is excellent and discusses similar tradeoffs between the two effects:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Combined_effect_of_velocity_and_gravitational_time_dilation

Comment: You should at least provide a brief explanation of the solution present in the links you provided. This will allow for future reference and let other people with similar, or identical, problems decide whether this solution is appropriate for their case or not.

Comment: @ZaellixA good point ! I added screenshots of what seems to me to best capture the information provided in the links.

Comment: I found a good explanation of the difference in predicted kinetic time dilation components for the eastbound vs. the westbound flight here: https://youtu.be/flfqLgSV0iA. If I understood correctly, the different gravitational time dilation components are due to the fact that the speed of rotation around the earth affects the gravitational acceleration. Faster rotation means less gravitational acceleration. They cancel each other out (?).

Answer (score -2):

Gravitational relativistic effects near the surface of the Earth is negligible. The time rate of the person in the plane from stationary observers on the surface of the Earth should be slower.

Comment: According to the sources provided in my answer, gravitation relativistic effects are comparable to the kinetic relativistic effects for a flying airplane. If you disagree with the linked Wikipedia article or the actual predictions of the 1971 Hafele–Keating experiment, please describe precisely which element of those sources you disagree with.